# Unable to boot from thumbdrive containing Windows setup

Tags: windows, boot, installation, bios, uefi

I just completed my build in an H510 with the following parts:

- B550 Aorus Pro AC
- Ryzen 5 5600X
- Asus Dual OC RTX 3070
- WD Black SN750 (1 TB)
- TridentZ RGB 16 GB (DDR4 3600 MHz)
- Masterliquid ML240L V2
- G.Skill MB750G PSU

I turned my PC on and was easily able to access the BIOS with all of my parts listed there. The next thing I did was I used Windows Media Creation Tool to flash Windows onto an empty 16GB thumbdrive. I plugged the thumb drive into the back USB port on my PC and restarted it. When I re-entered the BIOS, I found the UEFI and USB versions of my thumbdrive in the Boot options, along with my SN750. I changed the boot prioritization to:
1.) UEFI
2.) SN750
3.) USB

I then exited the BIOS and booted my PC but got stuck on the Aorus logo indefinitely (similar to this image):
https://external-preview.redd.it/-xKpOIIf_xyZ5QJn9pGGfTQXJEhodS48UEyzNz2W0mM.jpg?auto=webp&s=902331f369c306c850e6ffb90af69115c1e3793f

I tried enabling and disabling CSM in the BIOS to no avail (and I had the same results when enabling/disabling secure boot). The next thing I tried was prioritizing my USB to boot off of. I got better results with the computer showing the Windows logo but without a loading indicator (PC is indefinitely stuck here too). I really am not sure what to do anymore because it feels like I’ve tampered with the BIOS settings a hundred times now. I’ve even tried using a different thumbdrive but that didn’t work either.

Any help would be appreciated! I can provide screenshots or any additional information upon request.

Comment: Keep the CSM disabled for simplicity, you don't need it. Is the latest BIOS installed? have you tried to reset it to defaults? Which Windows version are you using?